# reject by app store because of App Store Review Guideline 2.5.2

Tags: ios

Your app, extension, or linked framework appears to contain code designed explicitly with the capability to change your app’s behavior or functionality after App Review approval, which is not in compliance with App Store Review Guideline 2.5.2 and section 3.3.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

i wonder AFNetworking framework is illegal？

Answer (score 0):

Is that the only thing they mentioned in the rejection? I've found that if my screenshots don't look great or if everything isn't put together "well", they start calling me out on a lot of other minor things.

Remember there is an appeal option. Don't be afraid to use it - I've done it and gotten it approved within a day of submitting an appeal.